# Cannot communicate/ping the turtlesim

Tags: ros, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through the tutorials and have reached point of using the turtlesim for learning about nodes, etc. I am trying to ping the turtlesim node, but there is no communication with the turtlesim. I have it running and roscore from 2 separate terminals and am pinging it from a third. Pinging the rosout node does work.

Here is the rosnode info for turtlesim:

Node [/turtlesim]
Publications:

- /turtle1/color_sensor [turtlesim/Color]
- /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
- /turtle1/pose [turtlesim/Pose]

Subscriptions:

- /turtle1/cmd_vel [unknown type]

Services:

- /turtle1/teleport_absolute
- /turtlesim/get_loggers
- /turtlesim/set_logger_level
- /reset
- /spawn
- /clear
- /turtle1/set_pen
- /turtle1/teleport_relative
- /kill

contacting node http://nathan-p850:45561/ ...
ERROR: Communication with node[http://nathan-p850:45561/] failed!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256511/cannot-communicate/ping-the-turtlesim/) by [nathanspotts](https://answers.ros.org/users/29622/nathanspotts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well after doing some research, I found out that my ROS_IP was not set correctly.  So, I followed the instructions [here](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/pr2/wiki/index.php?title=ROS_IP)  and set my ROS_IP to 127.0.0.1 using:
export ROS_IP=127.0.0.1

Hope this helps someone else.

---

Originally posted by [nathanspotts](https://answers.ros.org/users/29622/nathanspotts/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0